# Displaying information from a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, push

I have new inputs for a multidimensional array. The original inputs that are already defined are displayed correctly when called upon but the new inputs write as "undefined". I think it is recognizing the new inputs as variables. How do you get them to show up as a string?

```
var original = new Array(); //this is the array
function input(title, artist, ddate, genre, picsrc) {
    this.Title = title;
    this.Artist = artist;
    this.Ddate = parseInt(parseFloat(ddate));
    this.Genre = genre;
    this.Picsrc = picsrc;
}
original[0] = {title:"Hope II", artist:"Gustav Klimt", ddate:1907, genre:"Art Nouveau", picsrc:"gustav.jpg"}; //and so on
```

Values that are added to the array are taken from a form.

```
function addit(form) {
G = form.Title.value //as a test

original[original.length++] =  new input(form.Title.value, form.Artist.value, form.Ddate.value, form.Genre.value, form.Picsrc.value)

alert("your entry has been added")
alert(G) //value shows up in the alert
}
```

but when it is called back in this function:

```
$("#info").html(original[currentrecord]["title"]+"<br /><h2>"+original[currentrecord]["artist"]+"</h2>"+original[currentrecord]["ddate"]+"<br />"+original[currentrecord]["genre"]);
```

everything is being written as "undefined".
I am assuming that the data is successfully being added to the array, but maybe not in the right format?

Comment: What is the value of `currentrecord`?

Comment: what is the value of `original[currentrecord].title` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using dot notation, but it's not a requirement.

The real issue is: JavaScript is case sensetive.

I would do it like this:

```
original[currentrecord].Title
original[currentrecord].Artist
```

and so on...

At one place in your code you are using all lowercase (when initializing original[0]), but in the constructor function you are using uppercase for the first letter.

Comment: There is no benefit to using dot notation over what he's already using.  The case sensitive thing could be the issue though.

Comment: @JamesMontagne thanks, I've edited. I'm just used to using dot notation. :)